# indy 10, http proxy tunneling tcp server and client, delphi

Tags: delphi, sockets, proxy, indy, indy10

I'm using delphi xe4 with indy10 component. My software use Tidtcpclient and tidtcpserver and works perfectly on my local network and out of my network but with port forwarding or without firewall and this is my problem because i want to run my application without portfroward my router or firewall. I think that the best way to solve this problem when i need my software out of my network is to build a http tunnel that work with port 80 that isn't blocked and reconvert the original port tcp.   [image: http://i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg]

i tried to search on google and i found some component of indy that can do what i need(for example idproxyserver,idconnectthroughproxy...), but i have no idea how i can do.

I need to know how setup both side client and server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. You seem to be mixing up proxy servers and firewalls. There is a difference.

Comment: @KennethCochran i know the difference, my question is how to use http tunneling to avoid connection blocked by firewall,nat... because my application run on tcp port 8080 for example and through http tunneling i don't need to port forward my router or other beause it use port 80(for example teamviewer use http-tunneling for the remote control).

Comment: So are you asking how to implement an http tunneling client/server using indy or are you asking how to use indy to communicate with one?

Comment: @KennethCochran i'm asking how to implement an http tunneling client/server using indy. I'm sorry if i'm not clear

Comment: That is a major undertaking and not likely to get an answer. It would be far easier to use an existing commercial or open source project than to write your own. If you already had an implementation and needed help with a specific error message or connection problem that would be different. As it is now this question is not answerable. Try looking at [HTTPTunnel](http://http-tunnel.sourceforge.net/). Hey, that picture on their home page looks familiar. Now where have I seen that before...

Comment: i haven't already an implementation, i have only my application that work through tcp connection without any proxy or http tunnel.